# Failed to load libmysql.dll

Tags: ruby, cucumber

Please help me, I don't know what to do anymore.

```
$ bundle exec cucumber -t @login
```

Error:

```
Failed to load libmysql.dll from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/mysql2-0.5.3-x64-mingw32/vendor/libmysql.dll
```

Ruby version: `ruby 2.5.7p206 (2019-10-01 revision 67816) [x64-mingw32]`